# Работа функции date_diff() разница в минутах по разному на двух серверах

Tags: php

Каждую минуту cron выполняет проверку на то прошло 20 минут или нет.
На локальном сервере все прекрасно работает, на рабочем сервере на 1й минуте сразу же выполняет действие, код идентичный.

Думал что проблема в разнице времени php и mysql, но проверив время на обоих серверах, они совпадают, единственное что на локальном стоит время UTC, а на рабочем по Киеву.

Класс возвращает разницу во времени:

```
class Time extends Model
{
    private $now;

    public function __construct(array $config = [])
    {
        $this->now = new \DateTime('now');
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function getTimeDiffNow($date)
    {
        return date_diff($date, $this->now);
    }
```

Вызывается в следующей конструкции:

```
/**
 * @return array
 * @throws \yii\db\Exception
 */
public function getArrayOfBooking()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, created FROM booking WHERE status = 2";
    return Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
}

/**
 * @param int $period
 * @return array
 * @throws \yii\db\Exception
 */

public function checkPeriod($period = self::PERIOD_STATUS_WFP)
{
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($this->getArrayOfBooking() as $book) {
        $time = new Time();
        $date = new \DateTime($book['created']);

        $minutes = $time->getTimeDiffNow($date)->format('%i');

        $arr[] = ($minutes > self::PERIOD_STATUS_WFP) ? $book['id'] : false;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в настройках времени для php, причем в моей конфигурации для видимой части был использован php/fpm настройки.

Консоль использовала другие настройки.

Добавляем time zone в /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini